# Problem while installing virtualenv on AWS Ubuntu 18.04 AMI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

How to install virtualenv properly on AWS Ubuntu 18.04 AMI. I have tried various ways such as through `pip` and through `apt-get` but I am not able to either properly install or configure it. Whenever I am running command `virtualenv --python=python3.6 .venv` or `virtualenv --version` it is giving me this error:

```
ERROR:root:failed to read config file /home/ubuntu/.config/virtualenv/virtualenv.ini because PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
```

How to properly install and configure virtualenv?

Answer (score 0):

First check if Python3 is installed

```
apt list installed | grep -i python3
```

After that

```
python3 -m venv my_app/env
```